# nib class is different in different target?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, viewcontroller

I'm trying to write a unit test that setup the view controller, I've tried two ways to get the  view init, the first way is to use the bundle to load nib content and filter out the one I'm looking for, as follow:

```
MyViewController *controller = nil;
....
NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
NSEnumerator *nibEnumerator = [nibContents objectEnumerator];
NSObject* nibItem = nil;
while ( (nibItem = [nibEnumerator nextObject]) != nil) {
    if ([nibItem isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    controller = (MyViewController*) nibItem;
    break;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"nibItem class is %@", [nibItem class]);
        NSLog(@"nibItem is %@", nibItem);
    }
}
```

After these code finished, the controller still be nil, I've insert some logs to inspect the nib class(the %@ place holder), and it turns out is the same as MyViewController (at least both classes description did), and I'm so sure these code works very well in the debug/release  target, but it's not worked while I run the unit tests.

So is that means the classes is different although their classes description are the same?

The second way I've tried is use the initWithNibNamed:owner:options method, just simply specify the xib file name, but Xcode reply that the nib loaded but view outlet not set, the situation just as the questions describe I found, but I have double check that things have been setup correctly:

1. In Interface Buildedr, specify the custom class name
2. Add xib file to the list of copy build resources section in my test target
3. Link the tableview outlet to the interface file (though I can not drag the view outlet to my class, but it's auto pointed to the tableView in the class)

till now the only way I could get the test pass is manually to set the view controller's view and table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyViewController *controller;
NSArray* nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
controller=(MyViewController *)[nibContents objectAtIndex:0];
```

replace your existing code with this one , Hope this will help you.

Comment: It works! Thanks Gaurav Rastogi! BTW, is there anything that I could refer to to know why is that happen?